# How can I count a specific value in a mysql table and echo with php, how many times the varchar is in the table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL table with several varchars in a column. Now I want to count how many times specific varchar is in this column. Then I want to echo the number that was counted. Can someone tell me what SQL Code I have to use and how I can convert the SQL result to an integer in PHP?

My table:

[image: table]

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result  (no img only) as text

Comment: please add what you have done so far to help people to know how to help you

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a table with customers data called CUSTOMERS, one of its columns being "NAME".

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(NAME) AS TOTAL FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME
```

So you will get something like this:

```
    NAME | TOTAL
    -----+------
    John | 5
    Mary | 3
    Bort | 9999
```

If you want to filter by a specific name, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(NAME) AS TOTAL FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE NAME = 'John' GROUP BY NAME

    NAME | TOTAL
    -----+------
    John | 5
```

For the second part, it would depend how are you accessing data from your database. For example if you are iterating every row using mysql_fetch_array, and saving the row in a variable $row, you only need to do this:

```
$name = $row['NAME'];
$total = $row['TOTAL'];
```